# Mobile UI css Designs

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

This sound off topic but I honestly need a way forward, I have googled for 3 hours now but still no end product, although it might be I am using the wrong key term.

I have seen mobile apps with powerful designs like the foursquare apps etc I am used to using JQM default themes but I want to learn and be more creative with my themes. I have being looking for a crash course or any tutorials online but I have so far failed to spot one.

Please, does anyone have a link to one? Please if you do, provide it for me and you will be saving me hours of searching the net.

I am not really a professional on css but I am trying.

[image: Sample Designs]

Comment: A link to what? Mobile CSS is just like any other CSS.

Comment: How to customize the JQM Css

Comment: You'd just copy the styles you want to modify, edit the values and append them after the JQM CSS.

Comment: Working with jQuery Mobile is like working with any other web pages, just create your own design. If you don't know how then brother you are doing wrong kind of job.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is just inspiration. You can check out my pinterest feed.
http://www.pinterest.com/uidesignguide/